# How is geometry defined using ZFC?

Tags: geometry, set-theory, foundations

I've been trying to get a rigorous understanding for the mathematical concepts I learned in high school. I've been reading about how the real numbers can be constructed from the axioms of ZFC, but I can't find any information on geometry.

I've read about axiomatic formulations of Euclidean geometry, such as Hilbert's, but they seem to introduce new primitive notions.

I've read definitions of Euclidean spaces as sets, but I don't see how it's isomorphic to the synthetic geometry taught in high school. I'd like to be able to know the answers to questions such as:

- How is the concept of "angle" defined?

I thought ZFC was the foundation for most of modern mathematics? Doesn't this mean that it should be possible to describe basic high school geometry topics (circle geometry, cartesian geometry, etc) using ZFC?

My goal is to know that synthetic geometry is isomorphic to something analytically defined using ZFC, so I can know that any proofs in synthetic geometry will also hold in ZFC.

Sorry if this is impossible. I am very ignorant of how mathematics works.

Comment: If geometry has a language, axioms and it uses any "reasonable" logic as a backbone, then you can interpret it just like you can interpret the real numbers. I'm not sure that I understand the actual difficulty.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if it was possible to embed geometry into ZFC.

Comment: It is, in a similar way that we interpret the real numbers in $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or link a reference? I mean, I can understand how real numbers can be represented as sets (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences) but what about geometry? For example: what's a common ZFC set representation of an "angle"?

Comment: Classically, an angle is a particular real number in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. How do you usually define geometry? As something that happens in the plane or in the 3D space?

Comment: Yes, I am referring primarily to the 2D and 3D euclidean spaces studied in high school. Thanks for the definition, could you link a document that contains such definitions for 2D/3D geometry? I have more questions now that I want to research and read about, such as: given two lines that are perhaps represented as a set of tuples or something, how would I assign a real number from [0,2*pi] to the angle.

Comment: You don't have to work very hard to develop the basic geometry on the plane. After you've defined $\Bbb R$, you consider subsets and points in $\Bbb{R\times R}$ as your lines and points. It seems to me that you don't really understand how formalizing things into set theory works. Perhaps it would benefit you to learn some basic set theory and logic first.

Comment: I'm reading Elements of Set Theory by Enderton at the moment. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Yes, read the first chapter and a half of his book about mathematical logic too. You can do that at the same time as reading the set theory book.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.

Comment: "I thought ZFC was the foundation for most of modern mathematics?" *Sigh* ... many people still believe and advocate this old point of view. ZFC has absolutely nothing to do with geometry and, by the way, cannot really explain what is going on in algebra, topology and other related branches of mathematics. Of course it is *possible* to model all these theories in ZFC. But it doesn't mean that ZFC and therefore set theory is the most appropriate foundation for mathematics. If you want to understand the foundations and general principles of mathematics, you have to learn category theory.

Comment: @Martin: I think I have a reasonable basic handle on foundations of mathematics, but I only took one course that dealt with categories. So "have to"? I hardly think so. Of course, if you believe that mathematics should be founded on categories then it is advisable to learn category theory. But you don't have to believe that, just like you can sigh with exasperation whenever someone says that mathematics is what is done inside set theory.

Comment: Regarding your very first sentence: set theory is not "a rigorous understanding" of the mathematics you learned in high school. Founding mathematics on set theory is done for very specific reasons that don't have much to do with a desire for increased rigor.

Comment: Oh, well then I meant: a way of deriving everything from an accepted theory of fundamental principles. It just seemed odd to me that after reading about how ZFC was a "foundation" that I would have to accept new axioms in order to derive geometrical results.

Comment: @ignoramus, exists a set-theoretic version of Hilbert’s axioms: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.226.1166

Comment: @ГарнакОлэговытц Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, to develop "formally" a geomety you have two ways; call them *analytic* and *synthetic* respectively.

*Analytic*

This is our "good old" [Analytic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry) :

> a *point* in the space is a ordered triple of *real* numbers : $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$
>
> a *line* is the totality of points $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $u_1x_1 + u_2x_2 + u_3x_3 = 0$,
>   where at least one $u_j (j = 1,2,3)$ is different from zero
>
> and so on ...

But *real* numbers are definable in *set theory*; thus - **in principle** - you can translate into set-theoretic notation the equation of the line.

*Synthetic*

See Edwin Moise, [Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201508672) (3rd ed - 1990), page 43 :

> *space* will be regarded as a set $S$; the points of space will be the elements of this set. We will also have given a collection of subsets of $S$, called *lines*, and another collection of subsets of $S$, called *planes*.
>
> Thus the structure that we start with is a triplet : $<\mathcal S, \mathcal L, \Pi>$, where the elements of $\mathcal S, \mathcal L, \Pi$, and  are called *points*, *lines* and *planes*, respectively.
>
> Our postulates are going to be stated in terms of the *sets* $\mathcal S, \mathcal L$, and  $\Pi$.

Here are the first two postulates :

> **I-0** : All lines and planes are sets of points.
>
> **I-1** : Given any two different points, there is exactly one line containing them [we can "trivially" express the fact that the *point* $Q$ is *contained* into the *line* $l$ with the formula : $Q \in \mathcal S \land l \in \mathcal L \rightarrow Q \in l$ ].

We write $\overline{PQ}$ for the *unique* line containing $P$ and $Q$.

We define the relation of *betweenness* between (sic !) three points $P, Q, R$.

Then [see pages 64-65] : if $R,Q$ are two points, the *segment* between $R$ and $Q$ is the set whose points are $R$ and $Q$, together with all points between $R$ and $Q$.

The *ray* $\overrightarrow {AB}$ is the set of all points $C$ of the line $\overline {AB}$ such that $A$ is not between $C$ and $B$. The point $A$ is called the *end point* of the ray $AB$.

An *angle* is the union of two rays which have the same end point, but do not lie on the same line. If the angle is the union of $\overrightarrow {AB}$ and $\overrightarrow {AC}$, then these rays are called the *sides* of the angle; the [common] end point $A$ is called the *vertex*.

Finally, you can "close the circle" between this two approaches.

Assuming that we have defined the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* inside set theory [but I prefer to say that we have defined a *model* of the *natural number system*], and then the set $\mathbb R$ of *real* numbers, we can use $\mathbb R^3$ and call it : (three-dimensional) *space*.

*Comment*

What have we gained so far ? **I think** nothing more and nothing less than what we already have with Descartes' discovery of *analytic geometry* : an "embedding" of the euclidean geometry into the "cartesian plane".

Of course, the "basic" set-theoretic language gives us a powerful tool for expressing also geometrical "facts" : we can write $P \in l$ for : "the point $P$ is contained into line $l$", we can write $l_1 \cap l_2 \ne \emptyset$ for "two lines intersect each other", ...

But I think that speaking of "foundation for most of modern mathematics" can be mesleading.

Comment: With you except for maybe the last line. From what you said in the rest of your answer, it would seem that set theory is indeed the foundation of most of mathematics -- starting, of course, from different initial assumptions.

Comment: @DanChristensen - "foundation" is a loaded term... For sure set language is a sort of *esperanto* for math, a common (and simple) language able to express (quite) all math facts. About the "traditional" foundationals point of view of last century (Frege/Russel, Hilbert, Brouwer) to sat that set theory has dissiped the issue regarding "foundations" (i.e.certainty, evidence, etc.) it is hard to say.

Comment: But aren't the postulates new axioms? Can't we derive them from the ZFC axioms? What happens if we don't take into account any postulates, does that mean most of the geometry theorem true in the real world will not be provable?

Answer (score 0):

8 years have passed since the question was asked and no one has mentioned euclidean spaces...

1. If you really want to, you can define functions in terms of sets and prove everything based on the ZFC axioms.
2. Euclidean spaces can be used to formulate elementary geometry and can be defined in terms of sets and functions (see [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-56127-6) book for more information):
   An euclidean space is an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) with a real and finite-dimensional vector space together with an inner product.