# Can all points in a given plane be regarded as set elements of the plane?

Tags: geometry, notation

When asked if a point P is contained in the plane α, is it correct notation to write that P∈α if my calculations conclude that the point is in the plane? My question is if this is the correct notation. Does P(x, y, z)∈α mean that the point P is contained in the plane α?

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823561/how-is-geometry-defined-using-zfc

Comment: I think it depends on the axiom system you’re using for geometry. There are systems in which there’s an incidence relation between points and planes (a point “lies on” a plane), but planes are a separate type of object that doesn’t _consist_ of points. In such a system, using $\in$ wouldn’t be right.

Comment: This is exactly the type of information I was looking for to clear things up a bit. Thank you both very much for helpful answers!